# Category display using conditions

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy

I have a custom post type(events) created and has taxonomy(event-categories) with parent and child categories.
Since im not good in coding, i will try to understand all the help from here.

So what im trying to work out is when im going to create a new event post, you can only select one parent category, if the parent category has a child category, another block will display the list of child category based on the parent and you can choose multiple child categories. I really dont know how to.

I have my code snippets but i dont know how to code.